# convert curl query to ajax query using mootools

Tags: ajax, curl, mootools, nuxeo

I'm using curl to get json data from nuxeo, this my curl function

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json+nxrequest" -d 
"{ params:
        {
            query:'SELECT * FROM Document'
        }
}" -u Administrator:Administrator http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/site/automation/Document.Query
```

this function run fine, but now  (with ajax version) I have error http 500. this is the code of ajax version

```
function getData(){
        var uri = "http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/site/automation/Document.Query" ;
        var options = {  method : 'post', data : 'query=SELECT * FROM Document' };
        var myCall = new Ajax(uri,options);
        myCall.request();

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

data needs to be an object. though not sure in mootools 1.12 - which you appear to be using.

in theory:

```
new Ajax(uri, {
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        query: 'select * from Document'
    }
}).request();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/z5QzL/

Comment: thank's for your help but it's not running, i have the same error, so in my curl post i have this params -> "{ params:
        {
            query:'SELECT * FROM Document'
        }
}"  how can I convert this post in ajax ?! :)

Comment: see the js fiddle? this will send that as `$_POST['query']` (or whatever lang construct you have that holds post / request data).

Answer (score 0):

For Nuxeo to work, you need to make sure you these two things in your AJAX call (as you do in your your curl call).

1. Set `Content-Type:application/json+nxrequest` as a header.
2. Pass in full json as data `{"params":{"query":"SELECT * from Document"}}`

If you fail to do these things, you will get a 500 return.

Looking at the server log on Nuxeo (server.log) might help you decipher exactly what you are sending with AJAX and help with the debugging of your problem.